# Does "vow" have to be always accomapnied with "to make"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

I'm writing an essay, and I initially decided to set its title as `The vow at dawn` (referring to a particular vow which has been made between some people at a sunrise). Though, ODE examples often use "to make a (or the) vow" expression. Thus, I'm wondering whether  `The vow at dawn` is familiar enough to the ears of native speakers or I better stick to `The vow made at dawn`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[*Vow*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/vow) is both a verb and a noun:

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   : a solemn promise or assertion
>   *specifically* : one by which a person is bound to an act, service, or condition

While *make a vow* may be a common phrase, there is no reason at all that you have to use it:

> I just finished writing my wedding *vows*.
>   It's a *vow* that I intend to keep.

---

Also, titles don't need to be grammatical sentences (or even grammatical at all):

> - [*A Fistful of Dollars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fistful_of_Dollars)
> - [*The Curious Incident of the Dog in the Night-Time*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Curious_Incident_of_the_Dog_in_the_Night-Time)
> - [*Extremely Loud & Incredibly Close*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extremely_Loud_%26_Incredibly_Close_(film))

Or, in your case, *The Vow at Dawn*.

The title you use is up to you.